# SQLiteDatabase index

Tags: android, indexing, android-sqlite

I want to apply **index** on table.

But when i seen the table structure in **DB Browser** index was automatically generated for column which contains **primary key** of all table.

So is it necessary to apply index on other column of table ?

[image]

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984636/how-to-decide-when-use-index-on-table-column

Comment: thank you but i want to know about sqlitedatabase